# python csv reader, loop from the second row

Tags: python

In python 2.7.3, how can I start the loop from the second row? e.g.

```
first_row = cvsreader.next();
for row in ???: #expect to begin the loop from second row
    blah...blah...
```

Comment: you had the answer right there :-)

Comment: I should test the most obvious way before ask, this is a stupid question :(

Comment: no question is stupid. don't sweat it.

Comment: @user2207811 I'm glad you asked it, because up until now I've been doing something like `enumerate(cvsreader) ... if index > 0: ...`. :)

Comment: I second Wesley's comment -- specifically the "glad you asked" part. And thank you, Wesley, for answering -- and so quickly.

Comment: I'm glad to see this question somehow helps :) Thank you guys!

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
first_row = next(csvreader)  # Compatible with Python 3.x (also 2.7)
for row in csvreader:  # begins with second row
    # ...
```

Testing it really works:

```
>>> import csv
>>> csvreader = csv.reader(['first,second', '2,a', '3,b'])
>>> header = next(csvreader)
>>> for line in csvreader:
    print line
['2', 'a']
['3', 'b']
```

Comment: `.next()` was removed in Python 3. I'd use `next(csvreader)`.

Answer (score 4):

```
next(reader, None) # Don't raise exception if no line exists
```

looks most readable IMO

The other alternative is

```
from itertools import islice
for row in islice(reader, 1, None)
```

However shouldn't you be using the header? Consider a `csv.DictReader` which by default sets the fieldnames to the first line.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning the alternative! I'm not using the header because the specific csv file I'm dealing with has an empty header :P

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the 1st row contains the field names:

```
import csv
for field in csv.DictReader(open("./lists/SP500.csv", 'rb')):
    symbol = (field['ticker']).rstrip()
```